# Angularjs select view not update when ng-model changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have view like this

```
<select id="cooperatorId2" class="form-control mars-form-control" name="cooperatorId" required
                        ng-model="selectedCooperator" ng-options="item as item.name group by 'Cooperator' for item in userCooperators" ng-change="cooperatorChanged(selectedCooperator)" ng-disabled="!userCooperators.length > 0 || !showCooperator">
                </select>
```

and on my controller

```
$scope.cooperatorChanged = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedCooperator = item;
    //resetBookmark();
};

$scope.$watch("form.cooperatorId", function(newValue, oldValue){
    $scope.cooperatorChanged(_.find($scope.userCooperators, {'id': newValue}));

});
```

when $scope.$watch work, It finds the right item to update, but view not update

Please someone help me , Thanks

Comment: your `ng-options` is setting `selectedCooperator` to a string that represents `item.name`, but your `cooperatorChanged` is setting `selectedCooperator` to the full `item`.  since `item` is not a string, it cannot be found in the select list, and therefore can't be set in the view.  Either remove `as item.name` from the `ng-options`, or set `$scope.selectedCooperator = item.name` in your function.

Comment: incidentally, it isn't necessary to use `ng-change` and `ng-model` on the same select to set the same value; use one or the other. (preferably `ng-model`)

Comment: I don't understand why do you use `$watch` and `$scope.cooperatorChanged()`for this if you already set `ng-model` in your `<select></select>`

Here is the example http://plnkr.co/edit/2lyKZtIadvuCkYF6S865?p=preview

Comment: I use $watch , There are other controller change form.cooperatorId, so I need to update on view

Comment: were my comments not clear enough?

Comment: you should add `$track-by id`, just google for exact syntax of it. Why it happens generally is.. the item you are assigning is not there in the list.. the reason being a difference memory-address/reference.. if you `track by id` then it would be able to identify the correct entry from the list based on id rather than depending on memory address of it. `ID = any identifier column which can identify your row uniquely`

Comment: did the issue got resolved?